# Inserting data into tables ORACLE APEX (getting error, newbie onboard)

Tags: oracle

After some research I found a way to insert data into tables using this example syntax:

```
INSERT INTO room_type (id, max_capacity, description)

 WITH names AS ( 

SELECT 1, 2,     'Single - Standard room for a single person'  FROM dual UNION ALL 

SELECT 2, 2,     'Double - standard room for 2 persons'  FROM dual UNION ALL 

SELECT 3, 3,     'Triple - standard room for 3 persons'  FROM dual UNION ALL 

SELECT 4, 4,     'QUAD - Standard room for 4 people'  FROM dual UNION ALL 

SELECT 6, 2,     'KING - Room with king sized bed, single or double'  FROM dual UNION ALL 

SELECT 10, 4,     'Apartments - Room for a longer stay(Open kitchens, dryer, washer)'  FROM dual 

)
  SELECT * FROM names
```

This code worked just fine, and all the tables got updated. Then of course I decided to move on and tried to update another table with some similar code, but it just does not go through and is giving me an error message

I have the whole list created already, but as an test example I have this code, which only has few entries

```
INSERT INTO room (id, room_type_id, number, name) 
  WITH names AS ( 

 SELECT 2, 1, 102, 'Single 102'  FROM dual UNION ALL 

 SELECT 3, 1, 103, 'Single 103' FROM dual 
  ) 

SELECT * FROM names
```

Even though both tables are the same, the only difference is that `room.room_type_id` is a foreign key for it.

I always get into a error message

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tried to modify column names like adding quotes, but get another error message, i just need to understand why the first table works and the second one not, i tried removing `room_type_id`, still getting same.

I need this for making a hotel database project, and the requirement is to use `INSERT` command for inserting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a table you're inserting into:

```
SQL> create table room (id number, room_type_id number, number number, name varchar2(10));
create table room (id number, room_type_id number, number number, name varchar2(10))
                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

See what is the asterisk pointing to? Column name **CAN NOT** be `number`, it is reserved word (for a datatype). Change it to, say, `c_number`.

---

Pretend you never heard this: there *is* a way to name a column number, but I certainly wouldn't recommend it: enclose its name into double quotes, such as

```
SQL> create table room ("number" number);

Table created.
```

but then you have to enclose it into double quotes every time you use it, paying attention to letter case, e.g.

```
SQL> insert into room ("number") values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into room ("NUMBER") values (1);
insert into room ("NUMBER") values (1)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NUMBER": invalid identifier
```